# Android Web Request Title grab

Tags: android, function, sdk, request, web

Could you please help me grab the titles from this page : http://golfnews.no/golfpaatv.php , for example ? By titles I mean the **Bold** text next to the hour scheldule . I need to grab each text and then put it on the device's screen. That's my code :

```
package com.work.webrequest;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebRequest extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String trax;
        String aux = "";

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        trax=getPage();

       aux=title (trax);

        txt.setText(aux);

    }
    private String title (String trax)
    {
         String aux = "";
         int i,j,n;
         n=trax.length();
         for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
         {
            if(trax.charAt(i-1)=='2'&&trax.charAt(i)=='>')
            {
                break;
            }
         }
         for(j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
         {
            if(trax.charAt(j)=='<'&&trax.charAt(j+1)=='/')
            {
                break;
            }
         }
         System.out.println("n ESTE EGAL CU "+n+"i ESTE EGAL CU "+i+" SI j ESTE EGAL CU "+j);

         aux = trax.substring(i+1, j);
         return aux;
    }
    private String getPage() {
        String str = "***";

        try
        {
            HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://golfnews.no/golfpaatv.php");
            HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

            if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
            {
                str = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        return str;
    }


}
```

-> the function that I created , `private String title (String trax)` is not good enough , because it grabs only the first title .. Could you please help me with the reasoning or perhaps , with a better function ? Thanks.

Comment: It only grabs the first title because its just one string.  Have you considered a String array?

Comment: Yes , I figured out why it grabs only the first title . If I use a String array , what dimension will I put for it ? The number of titles , isn't the same from one day to another . Could you please help me with a function example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first time I would do such a thing... But you are welcome
By the way, this is the worst way to do this.

```
private String[] title (String trax)
{
     String aux[] = trax.split("program-info");
     int n = aux.length;
     String[] result = new String[i=1];
     for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        result[i-1] = aux[i].subString(aux[i].indexOf("<h2>")+4,aux[i].indexOf("</h2>"));
     return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you please show me the easiest way to do this ? I am a beginner and I don't know much in Android . btw , this function doesn't work for me.

Comment: this is simple java! `aux` must be a `String[]` not `String` and to get all the titles you use `for(int i=0;i<aux.length;i++)aux[i]`

Comment: Yes , I understood your function , it's just that the application crashes and I don't know why...

Comment: index out of bounds.. I've tried to edit the comment for some time now

Comment: `String[] result = new String[i=1];` i mean n-1!